# sencha touch 2 - how to manipulate history support

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i want to use the routing system to provide back-button support.  i am showing a list of items based on a record store.  when i handle the itemtap event `function(list, index, target, record)` i get a reference to the selected record which i pass to a new screen which i instantiate and show.

under this scenario, how do i instruct the history manager that i have moved to a new screen and enable the back button.  i see `application.redirectTo` but i would lose my reference to the record i want to use.  (redirectTo will push a new action into the history stack that includes the primary id of the record but that seems redundant as i would then need re-find the record based on the id when i handle the redirect.)

is there a direct way to tell the history object to advance to a new action and also enable back button support?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find how to do it easier. Here's how I do it in my application (with nested list).
I created controller with routing like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.ListItems', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
            refs: {
                    nestedList: '.nestedlist'
            },
            control: {
                    nestedList: {
                            itemtap: 'itemSelected'
                    }
            },
            routes: {
                    'item/:id': 'showListItem'
            }
    },

    list: null,
    index: null,
    target: null,
    record: null,
    showListItem: function( id ){
            var nestedList = this.getNestedList(),
                    store = nestedList.getStore(),
                    node = store.getById(id);
            if ( node.isLeaf() ){
                    nestedList.goToLeaf(node);
                    nestedList.fireEvent('leafitemtap', nestedList, this.list, this.index, this.target, this.record);
            } else {
                    nestedList.goToNode(node);
            }
    },
    itemSelected: function( nl, list, index, target, record ){
            this.list = list;
            this.index = index;
            this.target = target;
            this.record = record;
            var path = 'item/'+record.data.id;
            this.redirectTo(path);
    }
});
```

I've also overriden onItemTap method of nested list for all list changes now is done via controller & propper routing.

```
onItemTap: function(list, index, target, record, e){
    this.fireEvent('itemtap', this, list, index, target, record, e);
}
```

Hope it'll be helpful.
Write here, if you find better way, please.